# Laravel 5.1 remember me functionality is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working on laravel 5.1. I have created login functionality with the remember me feature.
I check user authentication with the help of auth function:

```
$this->auth->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $request->input('password')], true)
```

From login when I check checked box and submit login detail it will create a cookies token like this:

```
remember_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But when I am logged out by this function
`$this->auth->logout()`
the login does not show the filled previous login detail
and this cookies token is also destroyed.

Answer (score 17):

You have misunderstood how **Remember Me** feature is intended to work. It's supposed to remember users even if server session has expired or removed, e.g. after user browser is closed.

When user clicks **Logout**, they're explicitely saying that they don't want to be logged in anymore, that's why **remember me** cookie is deleted.

See some more details in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

Especially this part:

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout.